# Regex - how to avoid a certain group?

Tags: regex

I need to match a right bracket followed by a quote: `)"`

like the last two characters in this string:

```
He said "Free Willi (song)"
```

I use the following regex which indeed match them:

```
(?:\))(")
```

My problem has to do with the grouping: this regex results in two groups:

Group 1:    `)"`

Group 2:    `"`

I would like to avoid the first group and have only one group that includes the double quotes (because of some generic code that uses the first group only).

Is there a way to avoid the first group?

I thought I did it by using the `?:` on the left hand side of the expression, but apparently I didn't.

Comment: Don't capture it? `\)(")` should do.

Comment: This one also results in two groups...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use positive lookbehind,

```
(?<=\))(\")
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/aA1kN3)

It searches for the `"` just after `)`. If it founds any, then the corresponding double quotes would be matched.

Comment: This one works perfectly in the testing tools but unfortunately is not supported by Java (I haven't mentioned it in my description). But - thanks a lot - I'm sure it will help others!

Comment: The solution that worked for me is the "lookbehind" one - Thanks for that - I wasn't fimiliar with it.